# Customers who placed order both in this month and previous month for a list of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am trying to find count of customers who placed order both in this month and previous month. I have to find this from the beginning of last year. I came up with a query which obviously doesn't work. Can I get some help with this please?

Query:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', month_column), COUNT(DISTINCT(customer_id))
FROM table
WHERE month_column >= '2021-01-01' AND customer_id IN (
       SELECT customer_id 
       FROM table 
       WHERE month_column = month_column - INTERVAL '1 month')
GROUP BY 1
```

NOTE: month_column has only month number i.e., '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01' etc.
I am using postgresql.

This is my first stack overflow question. So, if I didn't abide by any rules, I apologize.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra couple of parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)`, to make the code clearer - for everyone!

Comment: `WHERE month_column = month_column - INTERVAL '1 month'` will never be TRUE.

Comment: You will need a correlated sub-query to relate current and previous month.

Answer (score 0):

To make this trivial, you can use 2 queries. Get customerID's from this month (insert into temp table 1) and customerID's from last month (insert into temp table 2). Lastly just inner join both tables on customerID

something like the below

```
SELECT customer_id
  INTO #thisMonth
FROM customer
WHERE month_column > DATEADD(month, 0, GETDATE())

SELECT customer_id
  INTO #prevMonth
FROM customer
WHERE month_column > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())

SELECT COUNT(customer_id)
FROM #thisMonth tm
INNERJOIN #prevMonth pm ON tm.customer_id = pm.customerID
```

Comment: Also just remember to get distinct customerID's in both queries from your order table

Comment: Wouldn't I have to change the date everytime?

Comment: Okay so if you want to avoid that then in your predicate you can use DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()). This way you will always get 1 months worth of data. I will also update my answer to include this :)